# Compare Two CSV files using Rshiny dropdown

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have two multiple CSV files and I am comparing 2 each using a package called 
Daff(https://github.com/edwindj/daff). Now I do want to select CSV from two dropdowns on the shiny app. The CSV is stored in the data folder

I have tried this code but I get an error 
*No file in directory 
Error in file: cannot open the connection*

UI.R

```
library("shiny")
library(daff)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Automated Data Dictionary Comparison"),
    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(

        selectInput(inputId = 'csv1',
                    label = 'Choose First Data Dictionary:',

                    choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                         full.names = FALSE,
                                         recursive = FALSE)),
        selectInput(inputId = 'csv2',
                    label = 'Choose Second Data Dictionary:',
                    choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                         full.names = FALSE,
                                         recursive = FALSE))
      ),

      mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput('contents')
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(daff)
server <-  function(input, output) {
   # Parse first file
   dataset1 <- reactive({

      infile <- input$csv1

      if (is.null(infile)){
         return(NULL)
      }
      x <- read.csv(infile[[1]])
      x
   })
   # Parse second file
   dataset2 <- reactive({
      infile <- input$csv2

      if (is.null(infile)){
         return(NULL)
      }
      x <- read.csv(infile[[1]])
      x
   })
   # Create comparison table (reactive as both of its elements are reactive)
   diff <- reactive({
      x <- render_diff(diff_data(data_ref=dataset1(), data=dataset2()))
      x
   })
   #Output
   output$contents <- renderDataTable({
      diff()
   })
}
```

Expected result is html output of differences between the old and current csv

Answer (score 0):

Please change your two cases of `read.csv` code to the below:

```
x <- read.csv(paste0("./data/", infile[[1]]))
```

**Update**

Full solution:

ui

```
library("shiny")
library(daff)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Automated Data Dictionary Comparison"),
        sidebarLayout(

            sidebarPanel(

                selectInput(inputId = 'csv1',
                            label = 'Choose First Data Dictionary:',

                            choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                                 full.names = FALSE,
                                                 recursive = FALSE)),
                selectInput(inputId = 'csv2',
                            label = 'Choose Second Data Dictionary:',
                            choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                                 full.names = FALSE,
                                                 recursive = FALSE))
            ),

            mainPanel(
                uiOutput('contents')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

server

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(daff)
server <-  function(input, output) {
    # Parse first file
    dataset1 <- reactive({

        infile <- input$csv1

        if (is.null(infile)){
            return(NULL)
        }
        x <- read.csv(paste0("./data/", infile[[1]]))
        x
    })
    # Parse second file
    dataset2 <- reactive({
        infile <- input$csv2

        if (is.null(infile)){
            return(NULL)
        }
        x <- read.csv(paste0("./data/", infile[[1]]))
        x
    })
    # Create comparison table (reactive as both of its elements are reactive)
    diff <- reactive({
        x <- render_diff(diff_data(data_ref=dataset1(), data=dataset2()))
        x
    })
    #Output
    output$contents <- renderUI({
        HTML(diff())
    })
}
```

Run App

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You could also look at the package compareDF - https://github.com/alexsanjoseph/compareDF.

Comment: how can I make it give HTML output table on rshiny main panel instead of outputting on Rstudio viewer

Comment: I have it in both using the above app. do you not see it in shiny?

Comment: Yes now I can be able to see it in shiny, Just one last question about it, How can I resize the table to be a bit smaller to fit the screen size